POWER BI - Subtraction based on 2 slicers
I have 2 slicers which filter different values from a column named Scenario in the main table.
I've created 2 different tables, each with the values from the scenario table and other with sum:
CALCULATE(
    SUM(2024_P13_POWERBI[Quantity]), FILTER(2024_P13_POWERBI,  2024_P13_POWERBI[Scenario] = SELECTEDVALUE('Scenario Selection2'[Scenario2]))
    
)

The issue is, I need a third card with the subtraction of 2 filters (selection 1 and 2) and it's not working at all:
VAR SelectedScenario1 = SELECTEDVALUE('Scenario Selection1'[Scenario1])
VAR SelectedScenario2 = SELECTEDVALUE('Scenario Selection2'[Scenario2])

VAR Value1 = 
IF (
    ISBLANK(SelectedScenario1),
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(2024_P13_POWERBI[Quantity]),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Scenario Selection2'[Scenario2]),
        2024_P13_POWERBI[Scenario] = SelectedScenario1
    )
)

VAR Value2 = 
IF (
    ISBLANK(SelectedScenario2),
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(2024_P13_POWERBI[Quantity]),
        REMOVEFILTERS('Scenario Selection1'[Scenario1]),
        2024_P13_POWERBI[Scenario] = SelectedScenario2
    )
)

RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(Value1) || ISBLANK(Value2),
        BLANK(),
        Value1 - Value2
    )

But it returns blank.
I hope someone could help on this one. Thanks!

Do some debugging and see if Value1 or Value2 return anything. Other than that, share your Data Model with any relationships.
